# Cauchy exercise

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the sequence ${x_n}$ defined by:

$$ \left\lbrace \begin{array}{c} x_1=\frac{1}{2} \\ x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt{1-x_n}\\ \end{array}\right.$$

then the sequence ${s_n}$ is defined as:  
$$ \left\lbrace \begin{array}{c} s_1= x_1 \\ s_{n+1}=s_n+x_{n+1}\\ \end{array}\right.$$

I have to prove that this sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

I was able to determine the general formula for the sequence $\{s_n\}$ which will be given by

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[2^{i-1}]{2}}\right)
$$

then applying the cauchy criterion
$$|{S_n - S_m}|= 
\left| \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[2^{i-1}]{2}}\right)
- \sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[2^{i-1}]{2}}\right)\right| $$ with $n>m$. \

As $n>m$ cancelling terms I am left with the following
$\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[2^{i-1}]{2}})$

then then applying commutaticity and leaving the 1's on one side and the sum of the negative roots on the other side I obtain the following
$ \sum_{i=m+1}^{n} \left( 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt[2^{i-1}]{2}}\right)= n-m - \left(\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[2^{i-1}]{2}}\right)\right)$

but I'm not sure if it's right and after that I don't know how else to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_i=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt[2^{i-1}]{2}}=1-\exp\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{2^{i-1}}\right)=1-\Big(1-\frac{\ln(2)}{2^{i-1}}+o(2^{-i})\Big)\sim\frac{2\ln(2)}{2^i}$$

Which is a term of a convergent geometric series so $s_n$ converge.

Note that the equivalence is not really needed you can as well upper bound it by the same term (since $1-e^{-1/x}<\frac 1x$ when $x>0$) and bound $s_n$ by the sum of that geometric series.

On the other hand $x_i>0$ so $s_n\nearrow$ and since bounded it converges.